# Customized IME in Samsung Smart TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am developing a app for Samsung Smart TV in which i have to implement search functionality.
I am using IME for taking input, like this:

I included

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/IME_XT9/ime.js'></script>
```

in body tag and then in JS

```
      ime = new IMEShell("txtSearch", ime_init_text, "en");
        if(!ime){
    alert("object for IMEShell create failed", 3);
            }

      function ime_init_text(imeobj)
      {


      var inputobj = imeobj.getInputObj();

      alert("start initializing : "+inputobj.id);
      var pluginAPI = new Common.API.Plugin();
      pluginAPI.registIMEKey();

     // ime.setKeypadPos(410, 80);
     imeobj.setQWERTYPos(200,150);
         imeobj.setEnterFunc(keypadEnter);
         ime.setAnyKeyFunc(onAnyKey);
         ime.setStatusOKBtn(onKeyOk);

     alert("ime_init end...");
     }
```

A nice qwerty keypad is coming, but i am unable to make its width equal to screen size of TV and handle its OK and Cancel button click events. Can someone help with this.